# Issues with desired effect getting detached

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using .js to create a russian doll effect. This works however it seems that dragging from the top will sometimes show an error where the heading becomes detached from the base. I'm not sure why or how to fix.

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hGR3H/)

HTML:

```
<div class='emails-container'>
<div class='column-header'>
<b>
Still Testing
</b>
<hr>
</div>These should lie on top of each other like a russian doll effect</div>
<div class='emails-container'>
<div class='column-header'>
<b>
Test Me
</b>
<hr>
</div>These should lie on top of each other like a russian doll effect</div>
```

CSS:

```
html{font-size:20px;font-family:Helvetica;color:red}.bookmarks-container{width:88%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.emails-container{padding-top:5px;width:140px;float:left;background-color:white;margin-right:10px;padding-left:10px;border-bottom-left-radius:10px;border-top-right-radius:30px;border:8px solid black; position:absolute; top:50%;left:50%; width:500px; height:500px}.emails-container:hover{border:8px solid red}.links{padding-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px}.links:hover{background-color:#B0E2FF;margin-right:10px}.footer{clear:both;padding-top:30px}.footer-container{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:50%}hr{color:red;border:4px solid black}a{color:#F87431;font-size:16px}.column-header{margin-top:7px}.header-login{text-align:right;padding-right:20px;float:right}.true-footer{width:40px;height:40px;background-color:white;position:absolute;bottom:20px;border-radius:40px;border:8px solid #1589FF}.true-footer:hover{border:8px solid #F87431}
```

javascript:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.drags = function(opt) {

        opt = $.extend({handle:"",cursor:"move"}, opt);

        if(opt.handle === "") {
            var $el = this;
        } else {
            var $el = this.find(opt.handle);
        }

        return $el.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function(e) {
            if(opt.handle === "") {
                var $drag = $(this).addClass('draggable');
            } else {
                var $drag = $(this).addClass('active-handle').parent().addClass('draggable');
            }
            var z_idx = $drag.css('z-index'),
                drg_h = $drag.outerHeight(),
                drg_w = $drag.outerWidth(),
                pos_y = $drag.offset().top + drg_h - e.pageY,
                pos_x = $drag.offset().left + drg_w - e.pageX;
            $drag.css('z-index', 1000).parents().on("mousemove", function(e) {
                $('.draggable').offset({
                    top:e.pageY + pos_y - drg_h,
                    left:e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w
                }).on("mouseup", function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('draggable').css('z-index', z_idx);
                });
            });
            e.preventDefault(); // disable selection
        }).on("mouseup", function() {
            if(opt.handle === "") {
                $(this).removeClass('draggable');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active-handle').parent().removeClass('draggable');
            }
        });

    }
})(jQuery);

$('div').drags();
```

Comment: Changing the last line to `$('div:not([class^=column])').drags();` seems to help.

Comment: Ok that works, it should continue to do so as long as all of the draggable divs have the same class? also this shouldn't interfere with any other elements on the page correct? Thanks for your help.

Comment: My idea was to apply `drags()` to the outer-most `div` of a draggable unit, rather than all `div`s in the document.  You might come up with a better selector than I did :).

Comment: I will try to create one that works best for me; I've never used the not notation that you applied to the script call; can you reference any resources for using that or similar alternatives.

Comment: jQuery selectors are documented here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/